# Ubuntu 20.04 still supporting Python2

Tags: python-2.7, 20.04

I upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04. Many articles mention that the latest LTS will not support python2. But I still have it. Why is that?

```
$ python
Python 2.7.18rc1 (default, Apr  7 2020, 12:05:55) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print "hello world!"
hello world!
>>>
```

Comment: Please don't provide terminal output as images. It is difficult for responders to use part of the output in their answers or in requests for clarification. Instead, copy and paste the relevant output here using this site's [markdown formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: @DKBose is it better now?

Comment: Couldn't be better! I'm taking the liberty of editing your question. If you disagree, you can roll back the changes I made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in [the Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Python3_by_default):

> #### Python3 by default
>
> In 20.04 LTS, the python included in the base system is Python 3.8. Python 2.7 has been moved to universe and is not included by default in any new installs.
>
> Remaining packages in Ubuntu which require Python 2.7 have been updated to use `/usr/bin/python2` as their interpreter, and `/usr/bin/python` is not present by default on any new installs. On systems upgraded from previous releases, `/usr/bin/python` will continue to point to `python2` for compatibility. Users who require `/usr/bin/python` for compatibility on newly-installed systems are encouraged to install the `python-is-python3` package, for a `/usr/bin/python` pointing to `python3` instead.

Answer (score 5):

"Support" is a somewhat strong word here. As you stated, you performed an upgrade, not a fresh install. Python 2 is not installed by default, and has not been for a long time, as it was moved out of the main archive into universe, after 18.04. There however, are still plenty of packages in universe which depend on python2, and therefore it is still in the universe archive.

As you already had the package installed, it would have been upgraded rather than removed.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers stated, python 2 is still the default python for some versions that upgraded to 20.04.

To change the default python, I followed this great article, using `sudo update-alternatives`. You'll have the ability to set python3 as default, but still change quickly to python2.

https://www.fosslinux.com/39384/switching-between-python-2-and-3-versions-on-ubuntu-20-04.htm